# SignalR example using Persistent Connection client?

Tags: c#, signalr

I am investigating SignalR, and I don't want to write a chat client.  I instead want to create a host with a Persistent connection and have a C# .NET client (not a web page) communicate with it.  Are there any good examples of writing a Persistent Connection client?

Or- is Hub really the only way to go?

Answer (score 6):

No, Hub API is not the only way. There are quite a few examples on the web showing how to use PersistentConnections (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/fa864e866bea4737dbd888f993892694f2f6b1a6/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples/Raw) from the SignalR repo - the client here is JavaScript but when using C# you just to just subscribe to the [Received](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/Connection.cs#L102) event - any time the SignalR client receives a message it will invoke Received event handlers). 
Hubs is basically a higher level API which makes using SignalR much easier. Persistent connections is about sending/receiving raw strings while Hubs is about invoking functions on the client from the server or the other way around. Hubs are, however, implemented as a layer on top of persisting connections where the messages are in JSon format instead of being raw strings and both clients and the server interpret them accordingly.

I described persistent connections and hubs in [my post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) on the SignalR protocol (for persistent connections see the *Persistent Connection Messages* section)

Comment: Thank you.  I also found this example helpful: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Persistent-Connections

Comment: I intentionally did not point you to this example - it is a bit dated and it uses `.Wait()` which in many cases is not right because it can cause deadlocks (it should be fine console apps though).

Comment: Ah thanks for the warning!  The Owin/SignalR/WebAPI ecosystem had indeed changed alot from 2012 til now.  It helps to be aware that some  of the more  helpful examples contain some legacy info.